# Why doesn't url rewriting work for .html extensions?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to get

```
/pages/Settings.html
```

to appear as

```
/Settings
```

by using the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z_]+)$       pages/$1.html                 [NC]    # Handle pages
```

in the .htaccess file. This does not work. However,

```
/pages/ANYOTHERFILE.php
```

works by using

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z_]+)$       pages/$1.php                  [NC]    # Handle pages
```

to be rewritten into

```
/ANYOTHERPAGE
```

Why does the former not work and the latter work? How do I get `.html` extensions to be rewritten like this?

Answer (score 0):

Add this rules to top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1.html [L]
```